# How to get Latex formula in inkscape on mac?

Tags: graphics, inkscape

I am using Inkscape version 0.48.2 on Mavericks OS X. I have to add latex formulas in some of the images but when I tried it through Extensions > Render > couldn't find the option there. After going through several blogpost I have installed the package pstoedit (through fink install) as well. But still I don't the option to type latex over my images.
Can someone help please?

Comment: You can read something `searching` inkscape tag: [inkscape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inkscape)

Comment: @cornelius I did try but couldn't find something that could have helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `textext`?

Comment: If you have a LaTeX full distribution, search inkscape via texdoc with `texdoc InkscapePDFLaTeX`. This document tells you how to insert SVG file with LaTeX annotations.

Comment: @HarishKumar I have read about `textext` and it appears that making `textext` work with inkscape on a mac system is much more complicated.

Comment: I don't have mac. But textext has problems with python libraries. Correcting that shouldn't be difficult. Refer to: http://laconsigna.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/fixing-textext-on-inkscape-0-48/,  http://pascalschulthess.de/inkscape-and-textext-deprecation-warning and http://dgleich.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/fixing-textext-on-inkscape-for-windows/

Comment: @HarishKumar I am looking for something simpler. I have no idea how to fix the python libraries or even what python is.

Comment: @cornelius I have looked up this document. This works if the images are to be used/processed through latex/tex. But I rather want EPS images that I can both use in my latex documents and use independently with other applications (a kind of work requirement).